# Remove Visualforce autogenerated html tags

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to get Visualforce pages with as clean HTML as possible. We have to meet a bunch of requirements for a customer, and are trying to remove as much as HTML additions added by Visualforce as we can.

Templates and pages were no issue, the bulky HTML generated for components could be disabled by using the `layout="none"` attribute, but I'm left with a little piece that I have not found to remove from my page. Added tags being the script and meta tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
<script src="/jslibrary/1344459698000/sfdc/JiffyStubs.js"></script><meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />

        this txt is located in the template

        this txt is located in the page (header define section) 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> this txt is located in the page (body define section) </p>

this txt is located in a component
    </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript doesn't seem to contain a lot of functionality:

```
var Jiffy={measure:function(){},mark:function(){},stat:function(){}};
```

The meta tags are in relation to cache I guess, yet setting the page attribute cache to false doesn't have an impact. **Can anyone explain the functionality of these additions, whether I can avoid having them on the page, or why they are important enough to Visualforce's functioning to keep them on there (if removal is possible).**

**update:** my Visualforce page is defined as following:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false"  cache="false">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Ryan Guest, the jiffy script can not be removed. It is not added to an empty page, but as soon as there is anything rendering HTML output the script is added.

However, the meta tags **can** be removed.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />
```

These dissapear when the cache attribute is **explicitly** set to true. Eventhough the documentation states that `"true"` is the default value, not setting it to `"true"` will result in Visualforce adding these meta tags to the page. Setting the argument to `"false"` will also result in Visualforce adding the meta tags.

Answer (score 3):

The Jiffy javascript is used for gathering performance metrics from visualforce pages by the salesforce team. There is no way to remove the script from visualforce pages.

It shouldn't impact end user performance or functionality at all.

Comment: An idea on the meta tags ? W3C considers them invalid in the latest validator, we've been given rather strict requirements html output wise.

Comment: You might want to look at the cache attribute on the page. I'll experiment and see if I can find anything useful.

Comment: JiffyStubs only contains the minimal function stubs (as referenced in other SFDC scripts) to prevent errors when performance is not being actively logged. More info on jiffy-web can be found here: [jiffy-web](http://code.google.com/p/jiffy-web/)